# How to create a Audio Device driver to capture sound Mac is playing?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, audiounit, iokit

I have created some code to do a screen capture to mov file using AV Foundation and my next step is to also record what sounds Mac is playing for later adding to the recorded video. I have done some digging and appears I might need to implement some kind of Audio Driver to capture the audio. Any pointers on how to achieve this?

I assume AudioUnit and IOKit will be needed in some manner...

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The book [OS X and iOS Kernel Programming](http://www.apress.com/9781430235361-4892) by Ole Henry Halvorsen and Douglas Clarke has an example that does pretty much exactly this. You can download the example from the book's website, the book itself of course explains how it works.

Disclosure: I was one of the tech reviewers for this book. (I don't receive royalties etc.)

Comment: I now need to work out how to route audio into the loop back device so i can capture its input, hopefully this can be done without muting the current playing sounds...

Comment: @Equinox2000 if I remember correctly, the example generates both an output and an input device. You can record from the input (microphone-like) device and store it to disk with a normal audio recording program, and set the output device as the system's default output. If you additionally want to *hear* the audio simultaneously, you'll need to also feed the captured audio to your sound card. You could either do this in user space (write a small program that captures audio from a microphone and forwards it to the speakers and also to disk), or if latency is critical, modify the kernel code.

Comment: for my purposes I'll probably modify the kernel code as mentioned to also push to speakers. I know applications like ScreenFlow / AudioHijack / WireTap work on a similar method but it is strange that you do not see an audio device listed in system - preferences - sound, how ever something like logmein does...

Comment: @Equinox2000 I can only assume those tap into the audio stream at a different location. I'm not an expert on the audio system in OSX, so I can't really help beyond what I've said already.

Answer (score 4):

You should also check out the source code for Soundflower:

http://code.google.com/p/soundflower/